# Assembly 8086 string displaying error

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have a very easy program in assembly 8086 for university purpose. The main components are working, but when I want to display 2 or more strings I have some special character, impossible to understand output. These are my first tries in assembly so lots of errors are possible, but I cannot figure this out.

The program would be very simple: first display the message "Welcome to my triangle area calculator!" then display "Do you want another try? y-yes n-no" and depending on the key pressed you can retry it or finish the program. Here is my code:

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'

WELCOME DB "Welcome to my triangle area calculator!$";welcome message

CONTINUE DB "Do you want another try? y-yes n-no$";other message

DATA ENDS


CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'

ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA

MAIN PROC FAR

MOV DX,OFFSET WELCOME;load the address of the welcome message in dx

MOV AH,09H; instruction for display

INT 21H; interrupt for display

XOR DX,DX; putting dx back to 0

XOR AX,AX; the same for ax

START:;loop label

MOV DX,OFFSET CONTINUE;loads the address of the other message into dx

MOV AH,09H; display intruction

INT 21H; interrupt for display

MOV AH,01H; character input instruction

INT 21H; interrupt for input

CMP AL,79H; comparison if the inputted character is y

JZ START; jump zero if it is

CMP AL,6EH; comparison if the inputted character is n

JZ FINISHPROGRAM; jump zero to finish the program

FINISHPROGRAM:

MOV AH,4CH; dos program ending

INT 21H

RET

MAIN ENDP

CODE ENDS

END MAIN
```

Comment: Maybe you should describe what the error is??

Comment: And you'd help yourself and us if you added comments stating what each of the system calls is -- it's been decades since many of us have looked a this sort of thing.

Comment: No compilation error, nothing and when the program runs displays me a bunch of special characters, then the welcome message and in place of the other message displays the welcome message once again.

Comment: Done with editing, now there are comments.

Comment: You say `assume ds:data` but you don't make it so.

Comment: LOL! Thank you very much! Without data segment initialization it would be hard to make it work. Sometimes I just laugh how unattentive I can be.

Answer (score 0):

try this......

```
.model small
.data

welcome db 10,13,"Welcome to my triangle area calculator!$"
continue db 10,13,"Do you want another try? y-yes n-no$"

.code
       mov dx,@data
       mov ds,dx

start: lea dx,welcome
       mov ah,09h
       int 21h

       lea dx,continue
       mov ah,09h
       int 21h

       mov ah,01h
       int 21h

       cmp al,'y'
       je start
       mov ah,4ch
       int 21h
end
```